# Add all subdirs in a QMake project file

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm porting an old project to Qt, and I have a lot of unit tests project.
Each unit test is a single executable.

Now my main .pro file looks like this :

```
SUBDIRS += UnitTests/Test01/Test01.pro
SUBDIRS += UnitTests/Test02/Test02.pro
SUBDIRS += UnitTests/Test03/Test03.pro
...
SUBDIRS += UnitTests/Test54/Test54.pro
```

Is there any way to include all subdirs at once ?
I would like something like this :

```
SUBDIRS += UnitTests/*
```

Thanks

Comment: Add least there are some loops mentioned in the project file description. Maybe you could try out that part?! http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html

Comment: Yes, but the loop is done over all values contained in a variable. So I still need to fill the variable with all subdirs name, which is I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Höher, this is working very well :

```
// Get a list of all .pro files
UNIT_TESTS_PRO_FILES = $$files($${PROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/Sources/UnitTests/*.pro, true)

// Add them as subdirs
for(unitTestProFile, UNIT_TESTS_PRO_FILES) SUBDIRS *= $${unitTestProFile}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use qmake's [files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false) function to locate all `*.pro` files and add them like this:

`SUBDIRS += $$files(UnitTests/*.pro,true)`

`files` expects two parameters: A globbing expression as first parameter and whether or not to recurse into subdirectories.